# My answer was downvoted and marked for deletion. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Then, after answered to the moderator's comment, explaining that have updated my answer and (with some irony, I admit) telling her that her way had not been the one of someone welcoming another to a community, she said "I'm sorry that...".

I know the beginning of her comment because I saw it on my stack exchange app.

I don't know the rest of her comment, because she kept her down vote and deleted her comments and mine even.

This is the thanks someone gets for getting out of his way to help someone with a challenge similar to some I had before.

My answer was about helping someone understand what [triggers someone wealthier to feel used](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/22169/11766).

This moderator distinction should be a power and responsibility given to someone who should act differently but well feel free to say that I am not better. I didn't deleted someoneelse's comments after this making that person feel unwelcome.

What else should I do about it?

I mean, I had already updated my answer to include a background to back my claims.

I believe this should be place to post this sort of thing. I really hope this wasn't a waste of time but whatever.

Comment: Hey Fabio, I went ahead and edited your post to remove the mention of a specific user because calling out users by name on meta is generally [not seen as a nice thing to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289913/316226)

Comment: ["Moderators"](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) refers to people with a diamond besides their name that can do things like removing comments. Normal users that have amassed some reputation points on the site gain some 'privileges', some of which include very limited moderation abilities. Please assume honest intentions. Would you have preferred if no one commented and your answer vanished out of the blue?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for explaining about the diamond. It may even have been someone. Sorry for assuming it was this particular user. Yet the question remains. It seems someone thought it was a good idea to delete things without being seen and unaccountable.

Comment: Please stop rolling back this post. The moderator requested that the post use the pronoun "they" or "she", and it's disrespectful to continue referring to them incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment you got was actually quite nice:

> I'm sorry, I didn't want to offend you in any way. We tend to flag and cast a delete vote (FWIW I wasn't the downvoter) on answers that are not entirely backed up to let enough time to the answerer to provide their backing up experience, so that they can ask for undeletion once they're ready. I believe the information you've provided is a great addition to your suggestion to OP so, thanks for helping them!

I am very proud of that user for reacting that way, especially after your previous comment was unkind enough, carrying false accusations of down- and delete voting and being as sarcastic as it was.

Your comment was flagged because it was so unkind. I forgot to check the timestamps and deleted the whole comment thread (The first one was no longer needed as you had added the backup, yours was unkind and the third one just chatty without the previous two). I should've left the last one for you to see, so you wouldn't be so angry right now.

> What else should I do about it?

You can't do anything else. You now have the text of the comment, notifying you that the user you suspected isn't the downvoter, and a cleaned up comment thread so there's no visible critique of your answer anymore.

I can't reverse the votes, maybe this meta post will be seen by the person that downvoted your answer and they'll reverse it if they find it's now a good answer (it has a pretty high chance, as most of our very active reviewers are also very active on meta).

Comment: @Thinkeringbell, thanks for replying. I realise I got very annoyed and perhaps got a bit on the unkind side as you put it and I'm sorry. I started by directing my feeling towards some user and then towards an unknown. I guess I just concern anticipating that my claim was going to be simply be dismissed which was a wrong assumption. On the other hand, now we all know how such actions can make someone feel. Whether moderators agree or not, perhaps, a little bit of education would go a long way towards avoiding misinterpretations on both sides. I mean, perhaps, a comment.

Comment: @Fabio No worries :-) I'm looking forward to seeing more answers (meeting our citation guidelines, of course) from you!

Comment: As for the speed with which things are happening, I tried to explain it a little in the [election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50732706#50732706) too: First posts end up in a review queue. Users seeing a post there review it. If it is lacking back up, they point it out, vote accordingly, flag, comment and then click 'Done'. Having users skip one step carries a risk of them forgetting about it later, or of never bringing your post to anyone's attention at all. So yeah, it's fast, which means 'please hang around for like 30 minutes or an hour after posting' ;)